# How to merge two lists(or arrays) while keeping the same relative order?

Tags: merge

For example,

A=[a,b,c,d]

B=[1,2,3,4]

my question is: how to generate all possible ways to merge A and B, such that in the new list we can have **a** appears before **b**, **b** appears before **c**,etc., and **1** appears before **2**, **2** appears before **3**,etc.?

I can think of one implementation:

We choose 4 slots from 8,then for each possible selection, there are 2 possible ways--A first or B first.

I wonder is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:
I've just learned a more intuitive way--use recursion.
For each spot, there are two possible cases, either taken from A or taken from B; keep recursing until A or B is empty, and concatenate the remaining.

Answer (score 0):

If the relative order is different than what constitutes a sorted list (I assume it is, because otherwise it would not be a problem), then you need to formalize the initial order. Multiple ways to do that. the easiest being remembering the index of each element in each list. Example: valid position for a is 1 in the first array [...]

Then you could just go ahead and join the lists, then generate all the permutations of elements. Any valid permutation is one that keeps the order relationship of the new indexes with the order you have stored

Example of one valid permutation array

```
a12b3cd4
```

You can know and check that this is valid permutation because the index of element 'a' is smaller than the index of b, and so on. and you know the indexes must be smaller because this is what you have formulated at the first step

Similarly an invalid permutation array is

```
ba314cd2
```

same way of checking